# how to check the call is from the which specific child controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, inheritance

I have two controller classes extending basecontroller.  I have a common functionality to be implemented and implementation is in basecontroller.

```
public class BaseController{


protected void populateWidget(List li, int zipcode){

//implementation for child A
populate only 10 employee records
//implementation specific to child B
populate 100 student records

}
}


public class ChildA extends BaseController{

List<Employees> li = ...
populateWidget(li, 90034)
}

public class ChildB extends BaseController{

List<Students> li = ...
populateWidget(li, 90034)
}
```

I have written setChildB method and working on it.  like below

```
public class BaseController{

protected boolean childB;

protected void setIsChildB(boolean childB){ this.childB = childB;}
protect boolean isChildB(){ return childB; }

protected void populateWidget(List li, int zipcode){


//implementation for child A
if(!isChildB())
    populate only 10 employee records
else
//implementation specific to child B
    populate 100 student records

}
}


public class ChildA extends BaseController{

List<Employees> li = ...
populateWidget(li, 90034)
}

public class ChildB extends BaseController{


List<Students> li = ...
setChildB(true); //setting as child B call
populateWidget(li, 90034)
}
```

Please advice the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend implementing a [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). You could have your base controller like this:

```
public class BaseController {

   protected abstract void getPeople(List li, int zipcode);

   protected void populateWidget(List li, int zipcode) {

      //Do generic logic here

      //Refer to child
      getPeople(List li, int zipcode)

      //Do some more generic stuff
   }
}
```

And then each of your children like this:

```
public class ChildA extends BaseController {

   @Override
   protected void getPeople(List li, int zipcode) {
       //Specific Logic here
   }
}
```

The children each override the `getPeople()` method to do their own thing.

That way if you need a ChildC, you can simply extend the parent without changing it.

**Update:** Based on the comments, here is an alternative way of doing this.

- I would not do it as a setter, rather I would make a constructor argument on the base class that takes the type of child as an argument. This makes sure that the compiler enforces that you will always have a value set
- You could use a `boolean` but I recommend strongly using an `Enum`, `String` constant or `int` constant.

*The above two points are mostly because I always anticipate that I might have to do a ChildC when some requirements change comes along and at that point you won't have to do changes to the base class. It also falls into the set of patterns that other programmers I work with would expect and therefore makes the code easier readable and maintainable by others.*

Sample base class:

```
public class BaseController {

   private int childType;

   protected static final int CHILD_A = 1;
   protected static final int CHILD_B = 2;

   public BaseController(int aChildType) {
      childType = aChildType;
   }

   protected void populateWidget(List li, int zipcode) {

      switch (childType) {
         case CHILD_A:
             //Handle Child A
         case CHILD_B:
             //Handle Child B
      }
   }
}
```

The child implementation would look like this:

```
public class ChildA extends BaseController {

   public ChildA () {
      super(CHILD_A);
   }

   //The rest of your code goes here...

}
```

*Note, that in the above example I am using integer constants for the sake of brevity. In the 21s century Java creating an `Enum` would be the preferred way to go.*

Comment: thanks for this design suggestion; one point to make; i don't have any implementation required in my childA or childB.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not quite sure what you mean by that. If you can explain that a bit more, I might be able to help you out better.

Comment: I have mentioned "//implementation specific to child B" this piece of code is specific to students. I agree, such specific implementation has to be override in my child class but am moving to BaseController because all the required variables are available in basecontroller. My question is I am using a setter method and checking if it is ChildB do this otherwise do this.  Is it appropriate way to do with a setter? or should i use getClass() or someother means of evaluating if this is a call from ChildB or ChildA, is there any spring MVC method to check if it is such and such child controller

Comment: So I laid out an alternative approach. Using a setter is not what I would recommend, because it is not enforced by the compiler and might create headaches years down the line when you (or another programmer) are trying to figure this out. For the very same reason I would also still recommend approach number 1, even if you have to pass 20 arguments to the `getPeople()` function. Other than that your approach will most likely produce the correct results.